# Thread with expensive operations slows down UI thread - Windows 10, C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, user-interface, opengl

**The Problem:** I have two threads in a Windows 10 application I'm working on, a UI thread (called the render thread in the code) and a worker thread in the background (called the simulate thread in the code). Ever couple of seconds or so, the background thread has to perform a very expensive operation that involves allocating a large amount of memory. For some reason, when this operation happens, the UI thread lags for a split second and becomes unresponsive (this is seen in the application as a camera not moving for a second while the camera movement input is being given).

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about how threads work on Windows, but I wasn't aware that this was something that should happen. I was under the impression that you use a separate UI thread for this very reason: to keep it responsive while other threads do more time intensive operations.

**Things I've tried:** I've removed all communication between the two threads, so there are no mutexes or anything of that sort (unless there's something implicit that Windows does that I'm not aware of). I have also tried setting the UI thread to be a higher priority than the background thread. Neither of these helped.

**Some things I've noted:** While the UI thread lags for a moment, other applications running on my machine are just as responsive as ever. The heavy operation seems to only affect this one process. Also, if I decrease the amount of memory being allocated, it alleviates the issue (however, for the application to work as I want it to, it needs to be able to do this allocation).

**The question:** My question is two-fold. First, I'd like to understand why this is happening, as it seems to go against my understanding of how multi-threading should work. Second, do you have any recommendations or ideas on how to fix this and get it so the UI doesn't lag.

**Abbreviated code:** Note the comment about epochs in timeline.h
main.cpp

```cpp
#include "Renderer/Headers/Renderer.h"
#include "Shared/Headers/Timeline.h"
#include "Simulator/Simulator.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


unsigned int __stdcall renderThread(void* timelinePtr);
unsigned int __stdcall simulateThread(void* timelinePtr);

int main() {
    Timeline timeline;

    HANDLE renderHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &renderThread, &timeline, 0, 0);
    if (renderHandle == 0) {
        std::cerr << "There was an error creating the render thread" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    SetThreadPriority(renderHandle, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);

    HANDLE simulateHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &simulateThread, &timeline, 0, 0);
    if (simulateHandle == 0) {
        std::cerr << "There was an error creating the simulate thread" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    SetThreadPriority(simulateHandle, THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE);

    WaitForSingleObject(renderHandle, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(simulateHandle, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall renderThread(void* timelinePtr) {
    Timeline& timeline = *((Timeline*)timelinePtr);

    Renderer renderer = Renderer(timeline);
    renderer.run();
    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall simulateThread(void* timelinePtr) {
    Timeline& timeline = *((Timeline*)timelinePtr);

    Simulator simulator(timeline);
    simulator.run();
    return 0;
}
```

simulator.cpp

```cpp
// abbreviated
void Simulator::run() {
    while (true) {
        // abbreviated
        timeline->push(latestState);
    }
}
// abbreviated
```

timeline.h

```cpp
#ifndef TIMELINE_H
#define TIMELINE_H

#include "WorldState.h"
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class Timeline {
public:
    Timeline();
    bool tryGetStateAtFrame(int frame, WorldState*& worldState);
    void push(WorldState* worldState);
private:

    // The concept of an Epoch was introduced to help reduce mutex conflicts, but right now since the threads are disconnected, there should be no mutex locks at all on the UI thread. However, every 1024 pushes onto the timeline, a new Epoch must be created. The amount of slowdown largely depends on how much memory the WorldState class takes. If I make WorldState small, there isn't a noticable hiccup, but when it is large, it becomes noticeable.  
    class Epoch {
    public:
        static const int MAX_SIZE = 1024;

        void push(WorldState* worldstate);
        int getSize();
        WorldState* getAt(int index);
    private:
        int size = 0;
        WorldState states[MAX_SIZE];
    };
    Epoch* pushEpoch;

    std::mutex lock;
    std::vector<Epoch*> epochs;
};

#endif // !TIMELINE_H
```

timeline.cpp

```cpp
#include "../Headers/Timeline.h"

#include <iostream>

Timeline::Timeline() {
    pushEpoch = new Epoch();
}

bool Timeline::tryGetStateAtFrame(int frame, WorldState*& worldState) {
    if (!lock.try_lock()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (frame >= epochs.size() * Epoch::MAX_SIZE) {
        lock.unlock();
        return false;
    }
    worldState = epochs.at(frame / Epoch::MAX_SIZE)->getAt(frame % Epoch::MAX_SIZE);
    lock.unlock();
    return true;
}

void Timeline::push(WorldState* worldState) {
    pushEpoch->push(worldState);
    if (pushEpoch->getSize() == Epoch::MAX_SIZE) {
        lock.lock();
        epochs.push_back(pushEpoch);
        lock.unlock();
        pushEpoch = new Epoch();
    }
}

void Timeline::Epoch::push(WorldState* worldState) {
    if (this->size == this->MAX_SIZE) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Pushed too many items to Epoch without clearing");
    }
    this->states[this->size] = *worldState;
    this->size++;
}

int Timeline::Epoch::getSize() {
    return this->size;
}

WorldState* Timeline::Epoch::getAt(int index) {
    if (index >= this->size) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Tried accessing nonexistent element of epoch");
    }
    return &(this->states[index]);
}
```

Renderer.cpp: loops to call Presenter::update() and some OpenGL rendering tasks.

Presenter.cpp

```cpp
// abbreviated
void Presenter::update() {
    camera->update();
    // timeline->tryGetStateAtFrame(Time::getFrames(), worldState); // Normally this would cause a potential mutex conflict, but for now I have it commented out. This is the only place that anything on the UI thread accesses timeline.
}
// abbreviated
```

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring this out!

So as it turns out, the `new` operator in C++ is threadsafe, which means that once it starts, it has to finish before any other threads can do anything. Why was that a problem in my case? Well, when an Epoch was being initialized, it had to initialize an array of 1024 WorldStates, each of which has 10,000 CellStates that need to be initialized, and each of *those* had an array of 16 items that needed to be initalized, so we ended up with over 100,000,000 objects needing to be initialized before the `new` operator could return. That was taking long enough that it caused the UI to hiccup while it was waiting.

The solution was to create a factory function that would build the pieces of the Epoch piecemeal, one constructor at a time and then combine them together and return a pointer to the new epoch.

timeline.h

```
    #ifndef TIMELINE_H
    #define TIMELINE_H
    
    #include "WorldState.h"
    #include <mutex>
    #include <vector>
    
    class Timeline {
    public:
        Timeline();
        bool tryGetStateAtFrame(int frame, WorldState*& worldState);
        void push(WorldState* worldState);
    private:
    
        class Epoch {
        public:
            static const int MAX_SIZE = 1024;
            static Epoch* createNew();
    
            void push(WorldState* worldstate);
            int getSize();
            WorldState* getAt(int index);
        private:
            Epoch();
    
            int size = 0;
            WorldState* states[MAX_SIZE];
        };
        Epoch* pushEpoch;
    
        std::mutex lock;
        std::vector<Epoch*> epochs;
    };
    
    #endif // !TIMELINE_H
```

timeline.cpp

```cpp
    Timeline::Epoch* Timeline::Epoch::createNew() {
        Epoch* epoch = new Epoch();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            epoch->states[i] = new WorldState();
        }
        return epoch;
    }
```